# Non Planar graph doesn't seem to contain neither $K_{3,3}$, nor $K_5$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

I am given the following graph G:

[image]

and asked to determine if its planar or not, and if it is not, give a $K_{3, 3}$ or $K_{5}$ that is a subgraph of G

I have determined G  is not planar. I have done this by using the circle chord method.

According to the theorem of Kuratowski:

> A graph is planar if and only if it does not contain a subgraph that
> is a K5 or K3,3 configuration.

I have spent hours trying to find the subgraph $k_{3, 3}$ or $k_{5}$ and cant find neither.

Do these subgraphs really not exist? And if thats the case, then G must be planar, but my circle chord method has repeatedly shown that it is not planar. I have therefore seemingly hit a paradox. Can anyone help me resolve this?

Comment: It does not necessarily need to have a subgraph isomorphic to $K_5$ or $K_{3, 3}$, but isomorphic to a subdivision of these two graphs.

Comment: Does your graph contain any of the arcs of the large circle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it mentioned in comment, it doesn't need to have a $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ as subgraph. Make $d \to e$, you'll have graph $G' \sim G$ with $K_5$ as subgraph.